# Hiding menu item in Odoo?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I want to hide menu item in accounting menu this is the full path:
Accounting/Charts/Chart of Taxes . I want this to get hidden so I've created custom xml file.but I'm unable to hide this one. instead of that can i delete this menu item using  tag??

can anybody please help me out this? Thanks

Comment: https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/hide-menu-for-existing-group-18704

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create one group using xml file this must be first added in **__openerp__.py**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
  <data noupdate="1">
    <record id="new_group_id" model="res.groups">
      <field name="name">New Group Name</field>
      <field name="category_id" ref="base.module_category_hidden"/>
      <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/>
    </record>
  </data>
</openerp>
```

And create another xml file in which update that menu item with that xml code.

```
<record id="account.menu_action_tax_code_tree" model="ir.ui.menu">
  <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6, 0, [ref('new_group_id')] )]"/>
</record>
```

That is enough to hide the menu item.

Comment: Can we hide that menu without giving any groups?

Comment: Yeah.. its okay what if i use ??
<delete id="account.action_account_tax_chart" model="ir.ui.menu"/>

Comment: Nothing is happening with that line okay .. i will try by my own if get any problem will reach .. thank you soo much for help

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same with `fields_view_get` method

Please try to pass some value in context from action
eg:

```
<record id="action_sample_record" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">student record</field>
    <field name="res_model">student.student</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field eval="False" name="view_id"/>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="context">{'student_master':True}</field>
</record>
```

Now override the `fields_view_get` method

```
@api.model
def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', toolbar=False, submenu=False):
    res = super(StudentStudent, self).fields_view_get(view_id, view_type, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)
    if 'student_master' in self._context.keys():
        res['toolbar'] = {'print': [], 'action': [], 'relate': []}
    return res
```

Hope this will help you. My code sample is for new api, but you can do the same for old versions as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
<record id="group_hide_menu"  model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Hide Menus</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="base.module_category_hidden"/>
    <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/>
</record>

<record id="hr_evaluation.menu_open_view_hr_evaluation_tree" model="ir.ui.menu">
    <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6,0,[ref('group_hide_menu')])]"/>
</record>
<record id="hr_evaluation.menu_open_hr_evaluation_interview_requests" model="ir.ui.menu">
    <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6,0,[ref('group_hide_menu')])]"/>
</record>
```

Comment: It lets you to hide two items  :) , I hope it helps you